# example of AlwaysOnHotwordDetector in Android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-5.0-lollipop

Can someone provide an example of how to use the new AlwaysOnHotwordDetector class in Android?

I'd like to build an app, that when the app is running in the background, can detect a hotword like "next", or "back", or "pause".

Answer (score 39):

Unless I have a huge blind spot, I don't think third-party applications can make use of this API. Its strange that `AlwaysOnHotwordDetector` (and related classes VoiceInteractionService etc.) have been granted public access.

---

**If you are building a privileged app**, look through these test projects from AOSP:

- Voice Interaction - Basic `AlwaysOnHotwordDetector` usage/implementation 
  http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/tests/VoiceInteraction/
- Voice Enrollment - http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/tests/VoiceEnrollment/

---

While trying to make this work, I came upon this:

`AlwaysOnHotwordDetector's` constructor:

```
/**
 * @param text The keyphrase text to get the detector for.
 * @param locale The java locale for the detector.
 * @param callback A non-null Callback for receiving the recognition events.
 * @param voiceInteractionService The current voice interaction service.
 * @param modelManagementService A service that allows management of sound models.
 *
 * @hide
 */
public AlwaysOnHotwordDetector(String text, Locale locale, Callback callback,
        KeyphraseEnrollmentInfo keyphraseEnrollmentInfo,
        IVoiceInteractionService voiceInteractionService,
        IVoiceInteractionManagerService modelManagementService) {
    mText = text;
    mLocale = locale;
    mKeyphraseEnrollmentInfo = keyphraseEnrollmentInfo;
    mKeyphraseMetadata = mKeyphraseEnrollmentInfo.getKeyphraseMetadata(text, locale);
    mExternalCallback = callback;
    mHandler = new MyHandler();
    mInternalCallback = new SoundTriggerListener(mHandler);
    mVoiceInteractionService = voiceInteractionService;
    mModelManagementService = modelManagementService;
    new RefreshAvailabiltyTask().execute();
}
```

The statement of interest here is:

```
mKeyphraseMetadata = mKeyphraseEnrollmentInfo.getKeyphraseMetadata(text, locale);
```

What does `KeyphraseEnrollmentInfo#getKeyphraseMetadata(String, Locale)` do?

```
/**
 * Gets the {@link KeyphraseMetadata} for the given keyphrase and locale, null if any metadata
 * isn't available for the given combination.
 *
 * @param keyphrase The keyphrase that the user needs to be enrolled to.
 * @param locale The locale for which the enrollment needs to be performed.
 *        This is a Java locale, for example "en_US".
 * @return The metadata, if the enrollment client supports the given keyphrase
 *         and locale, null otherwise.
 */
public KeyphraseMetadata getKeyphraseMetadata(String keyphrase, Locale locale) {
    if (mKeyphrases == null || mKeyphrases.length == 0) {
        Slog.w(TAG, "Enrollment application doesn't support keyphrases");
        return null;
    }
    for (KeyphraseMetadata keyphraseMetadata : mKeyphrases) {
        // Check if the given keyphrase is supported in the locale provided by
        // the enrollment application.
        if (keyphraseMetadata.supportsPhrase(keyphrase)
                && keyphraseMetadata.supportsLocale(locale)) {
            return keyphraseMetadata;
        }
    }
    Slog.w(TAG, "Enrollment application doesn't support the given keyphrase/locale");
    return null;
}
```

At this point, my example project kept telling me: `Enrollment application doesn't support keyphrases`. So, digging a bit further - to support keyphrases, we need to provide additional meta-data:

```
// Taken from class KeyphraseEnrollmentInfo
/**
 * Name under which a Hotword enrollment component publishes information about itself.
 * This meta-data should reference an XML resource containing a
 * <code>&lt;{@link
 * android.R.styleable#VoiceEnrollmentApplication
 * voice-enrollment-application}&gt;</code> tag.
 */
private static final String VOICE_KEYPHRASE_META_DATA = "android.voice_enrollment";
```

Additionally, we will need the `android.permission.MANAGE_VOICE_KEYPHRASES` permission. This is where the example project gets stuck:

```
<!-- Must be required by hotword enrollment application,
     to ensure that only the system can interact with it.
     @hide <p>Not for use by third-party applications.</p> -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_VOICE_KEYPHRASES"
    android:label="@string/permlab_manageVoiceKeyphrases"
    android:description="@string/permdesc_manageVoiceKeyphrases"
    android:protectionLevel="signature|system" />
```

The permission required to support hotword detection is not available to third-party applications. I still can't figure out why package `android.service.voice` package has public access. Perhaps I am missing something here.

Comment: Have you tried to run it? It would be great if we could access this API

Comment: @gregm Yea, I gave it a try. I needed `MANAGE_VOICE_KEYPHRASES` permission, which only system apps can request. I agree, it would be awesome if we could use this API.

Comment: there are procedures on how to install an app as a system app, has that been tested?

Comment: Are we still unable to do use it?

Comment: `android.permission.MANAGE_VOICE_KEYPHRASES` isn't even listed in Google's documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Comment: also, there's a blog about Always-On Hotword detection and after introducing `AlwaysOnHotwordDetector()` they quickly state `We can also detect hotword using Pocketsphinx library in Android` and that's it.. LOL! made me laugh

Comment: FYI: Google documentation https://developer.android.com/training/articles/assistant#implementing_your_own_assistant links to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/tests/VoiceInteraction/ (outdated link, of course, since we're now on P and Q - NOT M). Anyway, that sample code is missing `getKeyphraseEnrollmentInfo()` within `MainInteractionService` class. So it's totally useless.

Comment: Has anyone been able to do this? The links in the post don't work anymore (not even WayBackMachine has them) and for some reason, some examples I found on Google's site have non-working code. Would be really cool to know how to do this.

Comment: so, maybe that's why amazon had to partner with some smartphone vendors for integrating alexa?
But considering it have received some new updates in API30,hope, it might be available in future

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere I found that that method is missing only for normal apps. You need the hidden APIs to see it. I have it working here - though I don't know how to put the detection working. Too new to Android to know how to put all this working, even because the links have outdated things as you said, and I'm not sure how to update them). But you need those APIs. Here: https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api. That provides hidden and internal APIs. That method is included there. I'm using one for API 29 (from one of the Issues (search for "29"), as the main one doesn't work for me).