# Is there a way to voice activation by my own phrase?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I want to create a simple application which will make some tasks by voice commands. I want to start listening for commands with my own phrase like a "Hello device". Is it possible with Android speech recognition API? How to implement activation by my own phrase?

I was searching about this before asking, but couldn't find information about activation. I know about pocket-sphinx, but I need to implement it with Google APIs.

Answer (score 3):

CMUSphinx is a real solution for this problem, continuous speech recognition takes too much resources and will drain your battery in an hour while keyword spotting mode is fast enough to detect just a keyphrase.

You might be interested that Google introduced new API in v21 for the similar task:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/voice/AlwaysOnHotwordDetector.html

You could use that, but it will quite seriously restrict your userbase.

Comment: Thank you. It is interesting how does it work in the Google Now application with "Okay Google" keyphrase...

Comment: from my research it doesn't look like AlwaysOnHotwordDetector is ready for public use at this time, although the API doc is available.

[related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27537522/4033525)

Answer (score 1):

Send [`RecognizerIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html).

[Here](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/) you have a tutorial how to implement voice recognition.

> I want to start listening for commands with my own phrase like a
>   "Hello device". Is it possible with Android speech recognition API?

You cannot record a phrase, but you can listen to everything and then ask the recognition engine for words it heard.

Relevant code fragment from the tutorial:

```
// Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

So, you can check if it heard your plain English command, like "Hello device" and if yes, do something.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Yes, I already looking at SpeechRecognizer and RecognitionService classes. But I can't understand, is it capable of voice activation.

Comment: Adam, as I understand example from this tutorial can be activated only by button. As I understand here is no way to implement my own phrase for activation.

Comment: @BArtWell Correct. What you can do is to have it activated all the time, get words all the time and if some word is your command - activate something.

Comment: sounds like a terrible battery leak

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;

import android.content.Intent;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;
```

---

### Step 1: Put this into a method that will start the speech recognizer, you can name anything meaningful like void startSpeech() or something.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getClass().getPackage().getName());
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 3);
startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

---

Step 2: This will require us to override the onActivityResult() method to work with the above method.

### Then start to implement the onActivityResult() method below:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{

String wordStr = null; 

    String[] words = null;
    String firstWord = null;
    String secondWord = null;

    ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

    if(requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)

    {
        wordStr = matches.get(0);
        words = wordStr.split(" ");
        firstWord = words[0];
        secondWord = words[1];
    }

    if (firstWord.equals("open"))
    {

      // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }

}
```